# Slashes in CSS path

Tags: css, path

I have a strange problem with CSS path in source code. Everything works actually well but when I open the source code in browser I can see this:

```
<link href="https://testdomain.com/////////////////////////////////////?css=CSS/thumbss.v.1447957170" rel="stylesheet">
```

My code in CMS looks like that:

```
<link href="{stylesheet='CSS/thumbs'}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Why there is so many slashes and how to remove them? Website works well and I do not have any issues but I'd like to clean the code.

I work with EE 3.0.4 and Transcribe module.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:** I found something else. I have 3 languages, English as default. And the problem exists with English only. If I change the language the source code is as should be. Hmmm......

Comment: What is the value of your _Website root directory_ in **General Settings --> URL and Path Setting**?

Comment: My first idea was this one. I had https://example.com/ with https:// and slash at the end and changed for https://example.com (with https:// and without slash) but still the same. I found something else. I have 3 languages, English as default. And the problem exists with English only. If I change the language the source code is as should be. Hmmm......

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason and solution. English was set up as a default language and I switched off prefix for this language in Transcribe settings. Other languages have been set up with prefixes. When I switched on the prefix for English problem gone. However that's strange an looks like a bug in Transcribe.